# Segmentation fault error in adjecency list function

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to write a function that does some calculations with a graph that is represented by a adjacency list, but I'm getting a segmentation fault error that I just don't get. 
Basically I'm first "removing" a node and then re-inserting it again.
Here is my code:

```
int AdjList::bruteForce (node** list) {
    int pointerIndex;
    node* help;
    node* help2;

    for (int i=0; i<boundary; i++) {
        huidigScore = 0;
        help2 = list[i];
        help = help2;
        help2 = help2->next;
        while (help2->next != NULL) {
            help->next = help2->next;
            help2->next = NULL;
            pointerIndex = help2->number;

            help2->next = help->next;
            help->next = help2;
            help2 = help2->next;

        }   
    }
}
```

and the list initialization:

```
node** list;
node* help;
node* help2;
list = new node*[boundary];
for (int i=0; i<boundary; i++) {
    list[i] = new node;
    help = list[i];
    help->next = NULL;
    help->number = 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A minimal complete example would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your initialization help->next is always set to null, thus when it comes to

```
help2 = help2->next;
while (help2->next != NULL) {
```

help 2 is NULL and attempt to access help2->next in while loop leads to segfault.
EDIT
Same thing happens on last iteration of for loop, when i will be equal to boundary-1, help2 will hold pointer to the last value in list, with help2->next being NULL and everything will go by the previously described scenario. Thru I'm guessing here again about last entry in list having next set to NULL.

Comment: Well, after the initialization I load some values in it, so I don't think that's the problem. If I just use help->next twice or thrice it doesn't give me any errors, but if I use the while loop it does..

Comment: Then providing initialization code may help. Or even better example on how to reproduce issue. There is no way to guess what went wrong in code that one haven't access to.

Comment: I found the error, you were right. I added an if statement to check whether help2->next was possible, now it compiles. Thanks.